# Using S.browser_fallback_url in intent:// links to redirect to the app store using a market:// link

Tags: google-chrome, android-intent

I am using an `intent://` link to redirect users to an app, and hoping to use the `S.browser_fallback_url` field to redirect the users to the PlayStore if they do not have the app downloaded by setting the fallback url to be a `market://` link with params added in.

Is the `S.browser_fallback_url` only capable of handling web links? as in, it wont work with market links?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? Also, did you get `S.browser_fallback_url` to work at all?